# How to align text in tableview cell in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am developing a chat app in ios swift using firebase. I am able to successfully send and retrieve messages.

But the problem is that the entire message are displayed in either right or left direction. I want to display the sender message in right direction and receiver messages in left direction. With below code it either shows all messages in left direction or right direction.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellchat:TVCChatTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellchat", for: indexPath) as! TVCChatTableViewCell
    cellchat.setChat(chat: listofChatinfo[indexPath.row])
    return cellchat
    let cell = lachatlist.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
    let uuid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    if uuid == senderid {
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
        cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]
    }

    // cell.setChat
    //PostCell.
    return cell!
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: make two cells one is sender cell and one i s receiver cell. if object confrorms to sender deque sender celll otherwise receiver cell.

Comment: Can ou provide me more detail with code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints in storyboard (trailing and leading), then make @IBOutlets of them in your custom cell class, check if senderid == uid and change constrains. For example left one is 8, right one is 120 for messages for current user and left one is 120, right one is 8 for messages from current user.

If your code is good for you, then simply:

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]
if uuid == senderid {
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
} else {
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
}
```

Comment: i tried this code but it either shift all mesasages to right or left.

Comment: @farooqmughal did you try this instead of your code in if uuid == senderid statement?

Comment: yes i tried it. if uuid== senderid then it shifts all cells to right

Comment: are you sure, that uuid can be != senderid?

Comment: yes. when i save message to fire base. i saved with uuid . and while retriving i check first if uuid=senderid the allignment is right

Comment: Please, double check that else statement can execute (print something in it), because this code is working one. If 'else' statement is executing, then try to recreate the first part of my answer